# ¿Cómo puedo realizar la siguiente consulta SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Me encuentro realizando la filtración de datos desde una base de datos a través de consultas SQL y procesándolo mediante PHP, lo que quiero es obtener información según la semana del año en que fue registrada para su posterior interpretación.
Pero no se cual es la sintaxis correcta para traer los datos, desde una consulta SQL, que se encuentran entre un rango de dos fechas dentro de la base de datos, he usado la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT sum(botella) 
FROM barezzito 
WHERE idm = 17 AND 
WHERE fechavta BETWEEN 2019-05-30 AND 2019-06-03
```

Lo cual me arroja el siguiente error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE fechavta BETWEEN 2019-05-30 AND 2019-06-03' at line 1.

Que estoy casi seguro se debe a que quizá estoy redactando erróneamente la consulta, ¿De que manera debería realizarla?

Desde ya gracias por la ayuda que puedan brindarme.

---

**Nota:** Estoy trayendo la información mediante la siguiente estructura PHP:

```
$consulta = $conexion->prepare('
  SELECT sum(:tipo) FROM :cdc 
  WHERE idm = :idm AND 
  WHERE fechavta BETWEEN :fecha1_1 AND :fecha1_2
');
$consulta->execute(array(
  ':tipo' => $tipo, ':cdc' => $cdc, 
  ':idm' => $idMesero, 
  ':fecha1_1' => $fecha1_1, 
  ':fecha1_2' => $fecha1_2
));
$botellas = $consulta->fetchAll();
// valores: $tipo = 'botella', $cdc = 'barezzito',
// $idMesero = '17',
// $fecha1_1 = '2019-05-30', $fecha1_2 = '2019-06-03'
```

Comment: Tienes pegado el `AND` junto al `WHERE`. Deberías retirar el segundo `WHERE`. Además las fechas debes encerrarlas entre comillas simples ('2019-05-30').

Comment: Tienes exactamente que números de semanas del año son las que necesitas???...

Comment: Es por lo que dijo Damian. Como comentario, el mensaje de error si lo intentas interpretar ya te esta señalando el error.

Comment: Sí, no logre interpretar el error pero tienen toda la razón, gracias Damian y Ziggy.

Comment: @VíctorHugoTirado No había considerado hacerlo por medio del numero de semanas, pero ahora veo que es lo mejor y lo haré por medio de la función _week()_, tal como lo sugieres en tu respuesta. Gracias!

Comment: Me alegra haberte ayudado, recuerda si la respuesta es acorde a lo que buscas, por favor dala como respondida, ayudará más adelante a las personas que también tengan la misma duda...

Answer (score 1):

El problem esta en que estas repitiendo la palabra reservada WHERE y tus fechas tienen que estar entre comilla simple. Asi quedaria:

```
SELECT sum(botella) 
FROM barezzito 
WHERE idm = 17 AND fechavta BETWEEN '2019-05-30' AND '2019-06-03'
```

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo que tu consulta está correctamente hecha, en caso de que busques entre un rango de semanas del año, lo deberías hacer con la función *week()*, tu consulta quedaría de esta forma:

```
SELECT sum(botella) 
FROM barezzito 
WHERE idm = 17 AND 
WHERE week(fechavta) BETWEEN 21 AND 22 ;
```

Donde 21 y 22 es el rango del numero de semana de *fechavta*

**Aclaracion:** los datos 21 y 22 los saqué aplicando la funcion *week()* a las fechas que propones en tu consulta:

*select week('2019-05-30')* = 21

y

*select week('2019-06-03')* = 22

Answer (score 0):

Mira asi quedaria:

```
SELECT sum(botella) 
FROM barezzito 
WHERE idm = 17 AND fechavta BETWEEN '2019-05-30' AND '2019-06-03'
```